# When does structural typing's flexibility provide an advantage over nominal typing?

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand the implications of [structural typing vs. nominal typing](https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4). From reading, I've managed to gather that one of the key advantages of nominal typing is the ability to declare an interface that can be used with third party libraries where you can't edit a class declaration to add an interface. Unfortunately, none of the articles I read seemed to provide a compelling use case for creating such interfaces. In what kind of circumstances might this be useful and do structural types offer any other advantages over nominal types?

Comment: I came here by googling for the inverse actually. I happen to be shifting from coding a lot of TypeScript and Go to Java. And structural typing is something I miss a lot. :( I'm wondering if nominal typing has any particular advantages over structural typing. Would love to see a question where someone asks about that, if anyone can link one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you a real world example of this; names changed to protect the innocent.

We were integrating a rather expensive Hardware Widget from a Vendor. They helpfully supplied a C# class to interface to the widget:

```
class VendorWidget
{
    public void Start() { ... }
    public void Turn() { ... }
    public int GetPosition() { ... }
    public void Stop() { ... }

    ... a load of other functions ...
}
```

Note this class did *not* implement an interface. On top of this, we created a controller to encapsulate the business logic we needed. At this point, we actually wanted at least three different implementation of the widget code:

1. The real `VendorWidget` for use with the actual hardware.
2. A `SimulatedWidget` which we wrote so that developers who did not have the actual hardware could run as much of the system as possible.
3. Mocks of the widget for unit testing the controller.

With structural typing, we could have just created `SimulatedWidget` and the mocks to have the same functions as `VendorWidget` and carried on as before. But because C# is nominally typed, we had to first create an `IWidget` with all the functions we needed:

```
interface IWidget
{
    void Start();
    void Turn();
    int GetPosition();
    void Stop();

    ... all the other functions ...
}
```

Then wrap a trivial but tedious facade around `VendorWidget`:

```
class VendorWidgetFacade : IWidget
{
    private VendorWidget _underlying;

    public void Start()
    {
        _underlying.Start();
    }

    public void Turn()
    {
        _underlying.Turn();
    }

    ... repeat for all the other functions ...
}
```

and only then could we make the controller take an `IWidget` rather than a `VendorWidget` and code up the simulated widget and mocks.

Comment: Tedious as it may have been, it's arguably the right thing to do. (There are also ways of mitigating the tedium.) In the alternative approach, if the vendor renames a method, say, you would then need to make changes throughout your code rather than in one clearly delineated spot. (Renaming isn't too realistic but other changes to the API are readily conceivable.)

Comment: It's nice for devs to have the option though. They can take advantage of structural typing and have their code take a dependency on a dependency (hah) or they can use the approach here which centralizes the dependency on the dependency, and have their code depend on this code. Where this flexibility has helped me in the real world was with TypeScript, where I was able to make tests by passing in any object I wanted to functions etc, as long as it conformed to the structural type. Being able to make lots of tests quickly helped me ship reliable software.